# ValidFormBuilder - is it possible to have Custom Validation Function

Tags: validation

I am evaluating whether to use ValidFormBuilder and it looks great. However I have not been able to find a way where I can add my own custom validation function to a form. For example if a user enters an email address on registration I want to call my own function which uses ajax to check if the email already exsits in the database. I can do this using the jquery validation module  but I cannot see if it is possible with ValidFormBuilder. Can anyone provide an example of a custom validation function? It doesnt have to be an ajax one that does server side validation - any example would be appreciated. An example where I can get the value of the field I want to check and add an error message to the invalid field would be fantastic

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Or what did you end up using instead..